# UV4L from Mobile Hotspot

Tags: pi-3, hotspot, uv4l

I have attempted to use UV4L services while attached to an Enterprise type network and, due to the security, haven't been able to. My alternative was to use a tablet that I have as an access point via mobile hotspot. I am successful in connecting to it and I have Internet connection; however, when I attempt to go to Web UI provided by UV4L it says:

"Could not connect to the server."

I'm lost and out of options. Has anyone any advice on how to utilize the UV4L servers (which work so well on my home network)?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. The server is at home but you are remote? I suppose you have firewall / NAT problems. Not really much to do with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @ppumkin perhaps I don't know enough about UV4L and how it works. But at home, when I am attached to my home network (router), I can view my video stream by visiting "XXX.XXX.X.XX:8080". I am attempting to do the same while away from my home network. I have decided to use a mobile hotspot for the network. Now when I go to "YYY.YYY.Y.YY:8080", where this is the new IP assigned from the hotspot, I cannot connect to the server it says.

Comment: I meant... firewall issues. Did you open the ports required and assign them to the correct internal IP? (At home) ? Do you have a static IP or DynDNS? You have several things missing inbetween

Comment: @ppumpkin The tablet's hotspot will not be affected by the WAN's security.  The tablet *may* have routing issues though (which would seem stupid, but...).  You could check this by trying to ping the pi; there are various free tools around for doing this on mobile OS's.   Unfortunately the trend seems to be toward preventing actual ICMP pings on mobile OS's so these tools end up resorting to a sort of port scan, but it is worth trying anyway.  If you can't reach the pi at all, that's the problem.

Comment: @goldilocks I am able to ssh to the pi from my Macbook terminal.

Comment: @goldilocks pinging also works

Comment: So it is not the tablet itself you are trying to connect from, and that rules out a routing problem.   Hmph.

Comment: @goldilocks if this was a known process that I might have just been moronically omitting, I'm sorry. But I got it working by simply connecting the device that I want to use to view the stream to the same mobile hotspot network. While connected to a different network it didn't work. Maybe that might have been something you already knew was a requirement for this. If so, sorry for making you think of more complex solutions.

Comment: That would make sense.  I assumed it was also on the hotspot.   Although it is sort of off-topic and such you might as well add your own answer explaining the mistake (the system might make you wait to do that, there is a rep bar I think).

Comment: @goldilocks got it. Thanks anyway for the help. Really appreciate it. (this is a part of my senior design project and a very important feature that NEEDS to wok). Later.

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake that I made was not connecting the device that I want to view the stream on to the same network as the Pi. Once I connected my Macbook and tablet to the same network, the streaming server worked perfectly.